spring jpa get after saveAndFlush()
I have one javaBean like:
class testBean {
    @Id
    @UuidGenerator
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id1; //key, generated by database
    private String id2; //not key, generated by database trigger
    private String name;
    // other fileds with getter and setter
}

and then I use the JPA repository to save it like the code below:
testBeanRepository.saveAndFlush(testBean);// testBean's name has value

now I can find that the database has this testBean.
then I use findOneByName to try to get all the value of the testBean.
testBeanRepository.findOneByName(name);

However, the id2 value was empty despite being generated by a database trigger. I also mentioned trying to use @GeneratedValue on id2 without success. I'm using Java 8. How can I retrieve the id2 value after saving the testBean?

Clear the session, retrieve again. You will get the version that is still attached to the session not a fresh copy from the database.

how to clear the session? since I donnot find any method seems related to clear or commit in jpaRepository.

Inject entitymanager, call entitymanager.clear() run query. Of don't do a find after the saveAndFlush but after the @Transactional method has finished.

thank you. I injected the entityManage.clear(), it works.
but for Transactional seems not ok.
I have do the saveAndFlush in the method A with Transactional annotation. and do the findOneBy*** in the Method B with the annotation Transactional after method A. but still cannot get the database triggered value.

Try using the entityManager.refresh() method.

If everything is executed in another method that is @Transactional it will render the other @Transactional useless.
